# I can't await func() from __init__

Tags: python, python-asyncio

bot.py:

```
import asyncio
import async_bot_api
from util import User

bot = new_bot()
user = User()

async def get_username(id):
    return await bot.get_username()

#bot logic

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(bot.run())
loop.run_forever()
```

util.py:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id
        self.username = await get_username()

from bot import get_username()
```

This code don't working, i don't know how i can do that right.
Method `get_username()` little harder than that example.

Comment: You can't await things in `__init__` because `__init__` is fundamentally not async. But even if you could, your code wouldn't work because you don't await creation of `User()`, and you can't await it because you're calling the constructor at top-level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use one of the following examples:

---

Create a loop and run the `async` function using the [run_until_complete](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_until_complete):

```
class User:
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id
        _loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.username = _loop.run_until_completed(get_username())
```

Please note, this can run **only** if the loop is not already running.

---

Run the `async` function in an [executor (run_in_executor)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)

```
class User:
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id
        _loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.username = _loop.run_in_executor(get_username())
```

Please note, there are several issues you need to remember about this example:

1. You should have already running loop.
2. The function `run_in_executor` return a [Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future) and **not** the results.
3. The results **might not (with high probability)** be ready immediately.